# Highlighting changes from DataTable to binded DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on an app communicating with a database.

The app displays tables from the database in a DataGrid binded to a DataTable in code-behind:

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = _myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Data can be edited by users in two separate ways: either by directly modifying the data by double clicking a cell in the DataGrid, or using a mass override panel in which users select various parameters, enter a value in a TextBox, and click on a mass override button.

On this button click, data is modified directly in the DataTable by matching the fields through a link request, and this works fine.

I however wish to highlight cells that were edited by users. While this is rather straightforward in the case of in DataGrid editing, it is not for mass edits.

Indeed, for in DataGrid editing, I simply change the DataGridCell style by doing:

```
private void MyDataGrid_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            DependencyObject depObj = e.EditingElement;
            while (depObj != null && !(depObj is DataGridCell))
            {
                depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
            }

            if (depObj != null)
            {
                DataGridCell gridCell = (DataGridCell)depObj;
                gridCell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am looking for a way to perform something similar in the case of mass editing, but can't figure out a way to do that.
Would you have any suggestions on how to highlight in the DataGrid changes made in the DataTable?

Comment: Off the top of my head I think the best way might be to have a boolean for 'IsChanged' on the object you're binding to. Then have a style set the color of your cell to red based on a binding to 'IsChanged'

Comment: If you can't change the data object... then maybe catching a property changed event would be your best bet.

Comment: It makes sense but I'm not sure how to actually implement that. My DataTable is filled directly from the database using the Fill fucntion from the SqlDataAdapter object. How would you include this Boolean during the filling operation?

Comment: I also agree about the property changed event, but since my DaraGrid is bound to a DataTable because data from the database is not known at design time, thus making it impossible to bind to an ObservableCollection of custom objects implementing the IPropertyChanged interface. I'm not quite sure about how to catch such event on a DataTable.

Comment: ahh, I'm not too familiar with datatables but at first look, it seems like there's a few events you can catch for 'ColumnChanged' and 'RowChanged' that may help you. OR you may be able to utilize the DataTables DataSet.GetChanges() to find changes after your button click... just a starting point though.